# Calculation Of First Moment

Tags: integration

I'd like to calculate the following:

$$ \int y\partial_{y_2} [(y_1+y_2)p(y)] dy,$$ where $p$ is a probability density and $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ is a vector.

I need integration by parts here so I need the integral

$$ \int \partial_{y_2} [(y_1+y_2)p(y)] dy.$$

Do I need a volume integral here of the form:
$$ \int_\mathbb{R^3}\partial_{y_2} [(y_1+y_2)p(y)] dy_1dy_2dy_3$$

Could someone clarify this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing! What is the relation of probability to center of mass! Maybe the better word to be used instead of probability is **distribution**. Also, the center of mass integral is something like
$${\bf{\bar r}} = {{\int\limits_\Omega  {{\bf{r}}\rho ({\bf{r}})dV} } \over {\int\limits_\Omega  {\rho ({\bf{r}})dV} }}$$
I cannot find similarities between this and what is in your question! :)

Also, your first integral is some how strange! You have two vectors in the integrand with no operation between them! I mean $ydy$!

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I was only wondering whether my third integral is the way that the second integral should be understood. Also if $\rho$ is a probability density, then the integral in the denominator is zero. In that case your numerator is precisely the first moment of a distribution.

Comment: I still do not understand what $ydy$ means!? Anyway, if $y$ is a vector then you cannot write the second integral as the third one! :)

Comment: Ok, let me explain another way. Basically the term $\partial_{y_2}[(y_1+y_2)p(y)]$ is a term in a PDE. Consider for now as an example that $\partial_{y_2}[y_2p(y_2)]$ so that that $y=y_2$ only. Then I multiply by $y_2$ and I integrate to have $\int y_2 \partial_{y_2}[y_2p(y_2)]dy_2$, which can be integrated by parts to get $-\int y_2p(y_2)dy_2$, which is the first moment. I'm trying to ask what happens if I have p=p(y)=p([y_1,y_2,y_3]) and have the term $\partial_{y_2}[(y_1+y_2)p(y)]$. I'd like to get the answer in terms of the moments $\int yp(y)dy$.

Comment: So $y$ is **not** a vector, it is $y_1$ or $y_2$ or $y_3$! Am I right?

Comment: To be sure, I do suggest to write down the whole things from the PDE to the end in your question. :)